# Should each Application working-copy have its own working-copy of library projects?

Tags: svn, version-control

Let's assume some shared library projects called Graphics, Sound, IO, etc, and multiple applications which use these.
What's best, one WC for the shared projects and one WC for each application? Or each application has a WC and a distinct WC for the libraries?

I.e. the difference between:

```
src
|
|---libs
|   |
|   |---graphics
|   |---sound
|   |---io
|
|---project1
|---project2
```

And:

```
src
|---project1
|   |
|   |---libs
|       |
|       |---graphics
|       |---sound
|       |---io
|
|---project2
|   |
|   |---libs
|       |
|       |---graphics
|       |---sound
|       |---io
```

I can see advantages in each case but I think real-life experience would be really helpful here.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to make the libraries to be their own projects....

```
graphics
  +-- trunk
  +-- tags
  +-- branches


io
  +-- trunk
  +-- tags
  +-- branches

sound
  +-- trunk
  +-- tags
  +-- branches

project1
  +-- trunk
  +-- tags
  +-- branches

project2
  +-- trunk
  +-- tags
  +-- branches
```

And to use them inside the projects you should svn:externals to link io, graphics etc. to the particular projects which prevents copying the source code to every project and you have a single point where you can fix bugs and do enhancements etc.

Comment: They are separate projects and svn:externals are the plan... I'm asking whether each app should grab its own copy of the external dependencies or all share them.

Comment: You mean on the working copy level? Yes every project should use it's own. So the projects are independenant of each other and can be build separateley. If you like to share the dependencies you have to define some place where the dependenies can be found and that can cause some problems. On the other hand if you do some kind of build system you should be sure to be building separateley. So you are sure that everything is build correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In what way are these libraries "shared" if they're copied around all over the code base?

What advantages do you see for having libs under the app's directory?

Comment: Shared in SVN. Propose per-app working-copies in case you work on multiple apps and make a local change to a shared project. Advantages mainly if we have different branches of a shared lib used - the libs are under active development, not hugely stable.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have good reasons for supporting distinct WC of the libraries for all applications I would recommend using one WC for the libraries - it's easier to maintain the libraries this way (update, build).

The reasons for supporting distinct library WCs could be special stability requirements and moving to new version of some library only when it's needed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a Maven repository to store your binary dependencies, instead of a source code control system?

Dependency managers like [ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) can then be used to download jars into the WC as part of the build process.

Comment: The libraries are in active development, so probably it's not worth it. Most developers will work on at least one library if only to make bug-fixes.